# Link dynamic library with symbolic path instead of actual path in Xcode

Tags: xcode, dynamic-library

I'm linking some OpenCV dynamic libraries in my Cocoa app. When I add a symbolic link (libopencv_core.dylib), what is actually get added is the resolved real file name (libopencv_core.2.4.13.dylib).

[image: Real file name instead of symbolic link file name gets added.]

This is problematic, since in our office, people may use different minor revisions of OpenCV. Is there any way to make Xcode to use the symbolic file name instead?